# Regression with .csv tables

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am having trouble getting regression to work. If you wouldn't mind just looking over the code and point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it. I have loaded pgfplots and pgfplotstable packages.I am new to asking questions here, I apologise if I have made any errors in etiquette.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=left,
      width=\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
      xlabel=$\omega ^-1$, % Set the labels
      ylabel=Limiting Current,
      x unit=\si{\radian\per\second}$^-\frac{1}{2}, % Set the respective units
      y unit=\si{\ampere},
      %xmin=-1100,
      %ymin=-0.00004,
      legend style={at={(1,0.7)},anchor=north east}
    ]
    \addplot [mark=*,color=red,only marks,col sep=comma]
    table {Data/nRDE400.csv};
    \addplot [mark=none,color=blue]
    table[y={create col/linear regression={y=column 2}},col sep=comma] {Data/nRDE400.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{RDE studies of modified electrode in 0.5 M NaOH saturated with \ce{O2} and scan rate of 20 \si{\milli\volt\per\second}.}
\label{RDESCANS2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

My .csv file looks like this:

```
column 1,column 2
0.1545,6.4721
0.1093,9.1529
0.0892,11.2100
0.0773,12.9442
0.0691,14.4720
0.0631,15.8533
```

Comment: Hi Charles, welcome to the site! In general, it's preferred to include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of code snippets, i.e. a complete document (starting with `\documentclass`) that can be compiled without changes and that includes only the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem. The code I included in my answer is an example of how such a document could look in your case.

Comment: Hi Jake, thank you for the welcome. I am very excited to contribute and improve my LateX with the help of the people here. I understand what mean completely. I will be sure to post questions in the manner you have said from now on.

Answer (score 2):

The `col sep` key needs to go in the `table [...]` options, not the `\addplot [...]` options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [mark=*,color=red,only marks]
    table [col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \addplot [mark=none,color=blue]
    table[y={create col/linear regression={y=column 2}},col sep=comma] {data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Jake, thank you very, very much for your answer. It sorted everything out straight away.